# Is it possible to add a package to a Red Hat installation that is already in an USB bootable disk?

Tags: rhel, usb, ntfs-3g

If I already have a bootable USB disk with Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) in it, is it possible to add a package to it?

For example, trying to add `ntfs-3g` package to be able to mount a partition formatted with the NTFS filesystem from the rescue shell in RHEL.

I booted a broken Windows machine with my USB disk (RHEL) and chose the option to rescue, and when I get to the shell, I am unable to mount the partition `/dev/sda4` in my case, because it says it doesn't know the NTFS filesystem

Comment: It's probably easier to just create a new repo on it and add it at install time.

Comment: Thank you Ignacio, I am not quite following what you recommended. I am not trying to install anything, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: How did you create this "bootable USB disk"?

Comment: I used a tool called "Etcher Bootable USB Creator"

Comment: Then you'll need to ask the Etcher people how it can be done.

Comment: If you're not afraid of reinstalling, passing `expert` to the installer will let you install to a USB drive, giving you a predictable install.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible you will have to install the `livecd-tools` package from the EPEL repository, then create a custom kickstart file adding your updated package to the `%package` list then running.

```
livecd-creator -c kickstart.ks
```

The write the created iso to the USB.

[Red Hat knowledge base article 44483](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/44483) is suggesting the above tool. You may have also a look into the [man page for livecd-creator](https://linux.die.net/man/8/livecd-creator) utiltity.